# My website at AWS is not listening to my domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, dns

I have a domain which was working on a wordpress site hosted at hostgator. Was working fine. I have migrated the server to an AWS free tier EC2 instance, already setup nginx, mysql, php and everything. The site works when accessing the machine public ip, already inserted the domain at nginx sites-enabled/site.conf file but I can't get it to work. On my registro.br I have linked the dns to the urls given by aws route 53 after creating a hosted zone. Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

I've checked https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/gblanc.com.br and it shows some X and no error messages, not sure what it means

Some prints and nginx config file:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        listen 443 ssl;
            listen [::]:443;

        root /var/www/html/agenciaboz;

        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name gblanc.com.br;

        include snippets/self-signed.conf;
            include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
```

aws route print:
[aws route 53 print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9jXI.png)

my domain register print:
[my domain register print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8NJH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what it looks like in Route 53 you redirect `www.gblanc.com.br` to `gblanc.com.br`:

```
$ host www.gblanc.com.br
www.gblanc.com.br is an alias for gblanc.com.br.
```

but `gblanc.com.br` doesn't have an IP address:

```
$ host gblanc.com.br
$
```

You'll need to create an A record for `gblanc.com.br` that points to your EC2 IP address.  You need to understand that if you stop and start that EC2 you'll get a different IP address so you may want to look at using an [Elastic IP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html) that won't change.

Comment: yeah, I have made two records, one redirecting www.gblanc.com.br to gblanc.com.br and another that handles zone and dns, with master and slaves routes. 

Now i tried to make this A record with ony the external ip address as value input. Is it right? didn't changed anything else, but after saving nothing changed, maybe it take a few hours to propagate as well? Or was I supposed to input the internal ipv4? 

Oh I'm going to look into that elastic ip, thank you for that

Comment: Actually it worked, but there's a problem. When i go to that url it redirects to my ip address, and keep showing https://54.83.88.60/ 

Is there a way to keep the domain in url? And when I do the same with another domain, redirecting to the same IP (because i'm setting another site in the same machine, already configured nginx for it) it redirects to the ip address and loads the first site. The other domain is gblancjoias.com.br and it's root is set to a different folder then gblanc.com.br